# How to sort after removing `goto` statements, making it easier for people to understand?

Tags: php, goto

Maintenance of the company's previous project, the staff who wrote the project has left, now I need to maintain, but now the project uses a lot of'goto', I want to know how to read it.
How to sort after removing'goto'statements, making it easier for people to understand. For short, I want to format the messy code in the left side to be like the right side in the picture
[image: how to format your messy code in the left side to be like the right side in the picture]

```
//**this code
defined('IN_IA') or exit('Access Denied');
class Md_daojiaModuleSite extends WeModuleSite
{
    public function doPageUploadmap3()
    {
        goto A25dm;
        ADcuT:
        ZLMND:
        goto wJ44l;
        z_M2Z:
        if (empty($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])) {
            goto ZLMND;
        }
        goto RnW8Z;
        M61ng:
        $tempfile = ATTACHMENT_ROOT . "/audios/" . $name;
        goto ReGaV;
        A25dm:
        global $_GPC, $_W;
        goto z_M2Z;
        RnW8Z:
        $exname = strtolower(substr($_FILES["file"]["name"], strrpos($_FILES["file"]["name"], ".") + 1));
        goto BO3TT;
        wJ44l:
        return $this->result(0, '', "attachment/audios/" . $name);
        goto Qx8PP;
        BO3TT:
        $name = md5(time()) . "." . $exname;
        goto M61ng;
        ReGaV:
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $tempfile);
        goto ADcuT;
        Qx8PP:
    }
}
```

Comment: created a new account to ask again? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54300593/how-do-i-have-a-piece-of-code-to-make-it-easier-to-read-or-reorder

Comment: How did this task materialize? Have you been contracted to write a code deobfuscator? It's unclear what kind of answer you're looking for that matches up with the presented effort.

Answer (score 1):

You basically just reproduce what the interpreter would do:

1. From top to bottom, look at each [`goto`](http://php.net/goto) statement.

   ```
   goto A25dm;
   …
   ```
2. Shuffle the according jump marker and code section directly behind it.

   ```
   A25dm:                       # ← MARKER: starts section
   global $_GPC, $_W;
   goto z_M2Z;                  # ← next goto ends it
   ```
3. So you end up with:

   ```
   //goto A25dm;                # → no longer needed
   A25dm:                       
   global $_GPC, $_W;
   goto z_M2Z;                  # → proceed with step 1
   ```

Once you have associated each `marker:` right behind the `goto`, just remove or comment those out.

Comment: But you associate later, to'if', the real code return is outside'if'

Comment: 'goto ZLMND'is followed by'goto', so the program is incorrect if it is directly related, and the real code of'empty' is'empty'.